# Are there any serverside marker clustering solutions?

Tags: php, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps to display a lot of markers. Too many, in fact. I need to display at least 20000 markers, and that makes the JSON containing all of those markers (only latitude, longitude and ID for each) rather huge. To avoid sending this amount of data to client, I'm considering some form of the marker clustering. There are a lot of marker clustering libraries for the client. But what I need is the marker clustering on the server, to reduce traffic between the server and the client. Are there any libraries already available, preferably in PHP?

---

I have also heard about the `FusionTablesLayer`, provided with Google Maps API, but I didn't figure out from the docs just yet, whether it only helps to reduce the loading times or the traffic as well. Can it help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit old article though, this page helps you to use FusionTables and FusionTablesLayer.
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/